# How do we use LMS for noise cancellation in real-time?

Tags: least-squares, noise, noise-reduction, aec

The error to update the weights for LMS is given by:

`e(n) = d(n) - y(n)`

Assuming `e` as the error, `d` as the desired signal and `y` as the estimated output at given time step `n`.

How do we know the value of `d(n)` if we are using it real-time?
In a supervised setting, we would have samples for the desired output but how do we achieve it for real-time adaptive filtering?

Comment: highlight code and fix fomatting

Comment: You need the statistical knowledge of d(x), then you could use adaptive filtering techniques.

Comment: @abyesilyurt are there any specific techniques that you could suggest to do that?

Comment: For example, if your noise signal is additive and stationary, [Wiener filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_filter) is the best choice for [LMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarities_between_Wiener_and_LMS).

Comment: @abyesilyurt Thank you very much!